# Solving the Japanese Rope and Ring Puzzle using Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

I was wondering if I can solve/explain the famous Japanese puzzle "Rope and Ring" with the help of Graph Theory.

If you haven't heard about it, here is the image of the puzzle:

[image]

We need to move the Ring from one end to other.

There are solutions in YouTube, but I am interested to view the problem from Graph-Theory point of view,

Any suggestion/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a video link of its solution, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghqWSILCNZE

Comment: Why do you think Graph Theory might provide a helpful perspective?

Comment: Peter Kagey, I saw some puzzle solutions are well described with the help of Graph Theory,